# SQL Server Order By for reporting SCD

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table with a Slow Changing Dimension and I need to report from it.

It has 3 columns:
EmpId, Salary, StartDate

```
EmpId, Salary, StartDate
1, 1000, 2016-04-14
2, 3000, 2016-03-13
1, 900, 2016-01-14
3, 4000, 2016-03-14
1, 700, 2011-04-14
2, 2000, 2015-03-14
2, 1000, 2014-03-14
```

I need to display them in the order by Date, but keeping the Emp ID together
eg:

```
EmpId, Salary, StartDate
1, 1000, 2016-04-14
1, 900, 2016-01-14
1, 700, 2011-04-14
3, 4000, 2016-03-14
2, 3000, 2016-03-13
2, 2000, 2015-03-14
2, 1000, 2014-03-14
```

What will be the `Order by` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                MAX(startDate) OVER (PARTITION BY empId) maxDate
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
ORDER BY
        maxDate DESC, empId, startDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to do this before, but I had the partition incorrect so it did not work for me. After you gave the solution I got the partition correct. It works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
select temp.* from temp 
left join 
( select EmpId, max(startdate) r from temp group by EmpID) t
on temp.Empid=t.empid
order by r desc
```

**[SQL demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d447/1)**

**Explanation:**
We first need to find the maximum startdate on each EmpID and then sort all employee sets in desc order. In each set we sort again by date.

In above query

```
(select EmpId, max(startdate) r from temp group by EmpID)
```

provides the maximum date per employee and a rank on the date as well